# Batch file not echoing two lines

Tags: batch-file

My batchfile for some reason doesn't draw the two bottom lines inside the box. However when I copy the code to another batchfile, it works as intended. What's wrong?

```
for %%a in (
" %msg_error_1%"
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
"                 ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ"
"                 Û  %msg_error_2% Û"
"                 Û                                             Û"
"                 Û         %msg_error_3%              Û"
"                 ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ"
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
"                                               %msg_error_1%"
) do echo;%%~a
```

Comment: So just copy to another batch file

Comment: Check the encoding of your batch file in Notepad++ or any other advanced text editor.